# mysql data type for date and invoice

Tags: mysql, sql, date, sqldatatypes

I'm new in `MySQL` and I've got a problem: I want to create table `INVOICES`, that contains columns:

`DATE` - I know, it's easy to use `DATE` data type, but is there any way to display date in format `dd.mm.yyyy`?

`INVOICE_ID`: which should be in format `I/dd/mm/yyyy` i.e. `I/5/11/2014`. The letter `I` means invoice, the rest is a date.

Comment: You want the function `date_format()`.

Comment: The manual page for [date_format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) is most illuminating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **always** store in the native format of the database and then use the built-in date functions to manipulate the format. In your case, you would use `DATE_FORMAT()`:

> ```
>  DATE_FORMAT(date,format)
> ```
>
> Formats the date value according to the format string.

The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) provides a table of specifiers to output in your desired format.

To output in your desired format, you would use:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(your_date_column, 'I/%c/%e/%Y');
```

Which gives you

```
| DATE_FORMAT(your_date_column, 'I/%C/%E/%Y') |
|---------------------------------------------|
|                                 I/5/29/2014 |
```

[See it in action](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/d41d8/478)